# How to create folders when exporting OL to KML

Tags: javascript, kml, openlayers-2

I have this function that export all plotted features on my OpenLayers (2.6) map, by using the `OpenLayers.Format.KML` as follows:

```
var featuresToExport = [];
for (var i = 0; i < MAP.__layers.length; i++) {
    if (MAP.__layers[i].getVisibility() && MAP.__layers[i].features != null) {
        for(var j = 0; j < MAP.__layers[i].features.length; j++){
            featuresToExport.push(MAP.__layers[i].features[j]);
        }
    }
}

var format = new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
    'maxDepth':10,
    'extractStyles': true,
    'extractAttributes': true,
    'extractTracks': false,
    'internalProjection': MAP.__map.baseLayer.projection,
    'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
});

var kml = format.write(featuresToExport);
```

That way, all features are put at the same level on the KML. I would like to be able to arrange them in folders, for example for each layer.

How can I do that? The `write` function always write the complete KML structure, otherwise I could do something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < MAP.__layers.length; i++) {
    if (MAP.__layers[i].getVisibility() && MAP.__layers[i].features != null) {
        featuresToExport = [];

        kml += "<Folder><name>Layer " + i + "</name>";

        for(var j = 0; j < MAP.__layers[i].features.length; j++){
            featuresToExport.push(MAP.__layers[i].features[j]);
        }
        // write this features
        kml += format.write(featuresToExport);
        kml += "</Folder>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so in the absence of a better solution, I'll just cut the parts I want and rearrange the hierarchy.

```
var kml = "<kml xmlns='http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0'>";
    kml += "<Folder><name>My export</name><description>Some description</description>";
var layerString = "";

// Write features into a KML string
for (var i = 0; i < MAP.__layers.length; i++) {
    if (MAP.__layers[i].getVisibility() && MAP.__layers[i].features != null) {
        featuresToExport = [];

        kml += "<Folder><name>Layer " + i + "</name>";

        for(var j = 0; j < MAP.__layers[i].features.length; j++){
            featuresToExport.push(MAP.__layers[i].features[j]);
        }
        // write this features
        layerString = format.write(featuresToExport);
        kml += layerString.match("<\/description>(.*)<\/Folder>")[1];
        kml += "</Folder>";
    }
}
kml += "</Folder></kml>";
```

**Edit:**
Better than that is to use jQuery.parseXML and work with the DOM objects instead of string.

```
layerString = format.write(featuresToExport);
layerDOM = $.parseXML(layerString);
layerDOM = $(layerDOM).find("Folder")[0];
```